# MVC Ajax call not stopping at break point in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am debugging my MVC application in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

My view, which is a Search page, has a button then then executes the search using an Ajax Post to the controller action (in the same project) to get the results (as a partial view) and then load into a DIV in the page.

The problem is that I am trying the break on the search controller action but Visual Studio is not stopping when called via the Ajax post... however, it IS breaking when the main form initially loads up (to execute the default search).

**UPDATE**

I think Visual Studio may have broken as a result of installed VS2015 Update 1 as lots of things appear to be going exceptionally wrong.

Comment: show your code for clear understanding

Comment: You need to show your ajax code and your controller function for that ajax call, for anyone to see what might be wrong. Since the breakpoint is not hitting, my guess is the ajax call never fires or it is not "addressed" to that particular function. Double check that you do not have any java script errors stopping the ajax call from ever calling home.

Comment: See UPDATE - but the ajax process does actually work because it is filling the aforementioned DIV with data, just not the right stuff... I just needed to check some other facets of it.